# Is local compactness a topological property? Moreover if any metric space say $Y$ is locally compact then is the space $Y^n$ also locally compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Is local compactness a topological property?

Moreover if any metric space say $Y$ is locally compact then is the space $Y^n$ also locally compact?

In particular, do homeomorphisms preserve localness of any topological property?

Comment: Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: How do *you* define local compactness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, so many questions. Local compactness is a topological property (i.e a space is locally compact if every point has a base of compact neighborhoods). When talking about the product, we need to ask a bit more of the space. There is a theorem (check this url for more info https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space) that states the following: Let ${(X_j,T_j)_{j\in J}}$ be a non-empty family of non-empty spaces. Then the product is locally compact iff every space is locally compact and every space is compact minus a finite number of spaces.
Finally, local compacity *is* a topologically invariant property.

Comment: Well so many question but one last; So in what sequence can we put the properties: Locally compact, hemicompact, sigma compact?  I mean how are these terms related?

Comment: A locally compact and Lindelöf space is hemicompact. Every hemicompact space is sigma compact (the reciprocal does not hold).

Comment: And what relation can be drawn between the hemicompact and separability?

Comment: I don't really know, but I don't see a relationship right now. There is Baire's theorem, which is somewhat related...

Comment: @MirAaliya there is no relation between hemicompactness and separability.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks for your reply. Now may i know if Lindelofness imply anyone of the compactness such as; locally compact, hemicompact, sigma compact?

Comment: @MirAaliya no the Sorgenfrey line is hereditarily separable, hereditarily Lindelöf but not locally compact, \sigma$-compact or hemicompact.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a topological property: it's defined purely in terms of set theory and open sets.

And for any space $Y$ (not only metric) we have that $Y$ locally compact implies $Y^n$ is for finite $n$. (for all usual non-equivalent definitions of local compactness).

That homeomorphisms preserve this property is the definition of a topological property. The last question might depend on how you define "locally P" for a property $P$. If you say $X$ is locally $P$ iff every point has a neighbourhood (in the general sense) that has $P$, and $P$ is itself a topological property, then yes, so is locally $P$, obviously. You need that a homeomorphisms preserves open sets and hence neighourhoods and is surjective, so that all points in the image are reached.

Comment: If we have, for a metric space say $Y$, $Y^n$ for some integer $n$ is separable locally compact, can we say that $Y$ itself is separable locally compact?

Comment: @MirAaliya yes. Open continuous images preserve both properties.

Comment: May i know where comes the concept of open continuous images? I am just asking about an element of a product .

Comment: @MirAaliya Any projection $Y^n \to Y$ is an open continuous map. Local compactness isn't about elements it's about the space.